# Vuetify css over-ride changing the view of a component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a component to render some products, both mobile view and desktop view has different styles. I assign classes for desktop and mobile inside the `<div>` according to the requirement desktop and mobile view `div`'s CSS display attribute `display:none;` and `display:block;` changed.

On mobile view I have to display a `row` and inside two products will be display so I code it as follows:

```
<!-- MOBILE ONLY PRODUCT DISPLAY COMPONENT-->

    <v-row class="mobile_product_view ">
       <v-col cols="6">aa</v-col>
       <v-col cols="6">bb</v-col>
    </v-row>

/* CSS large mobile size */
@media screen and (min-width: 425px) {
  .mobile_product_view {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**Question**:

Without assigning `class="mobile_product_view "` attribute to `<row>` it render the columns as what i want. when i assign the class attribute the columns display one under another. what i want is cols should be half of full display `col - aa and col - bb` should be place in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with following code

```
<v-card class="mobile_product_view">
  <v-row class="m-0  ">
    <v-col cols="6">aa</v-col>
    <v-col cols="6">bb</v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-card>
```